# Se cierra la app al hacer clickear botón

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo una app en la que al clickear un botón en la pantalla de home me lleve a otra Activity en la cual hay un fab que ejecuta la camára. Lo que ocurre es que al hacer click en el botón "estudiante" que me debe llevar a la Activity "estudiante" la app se cierra.

---

Este es el intent del botón "estudiante" que está en la ACtivity home y que me lleva a la activity "Estudiante":

```
 public void btnEstudiantes(View view){
        Intent estudiantes_button = new Intent(this, Estudiantes.class);
        startActivity(estudiantes_button);
    }
```

---

Esta es la Activity "Estudiante" donde quiero ejecutar la cámara al apretar el Fab.

```
public class Estudiantes extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    Button fabCamara;
    ImageView ivfoto;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_estudiantes);
        fabCamara = findViewById(R.id.fabCamara);
        ivfoto = findViewById(R.id.ivfoto);

        fabCamara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                iniciarCamara();
            }
        });
    }



    

    private void iniciarCamara(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imgBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ivfoto.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
        }
    }

}
```

---

Este es el logcat:

2021-04-03 17:52:45.321 21586-21586/com.totoria.tutoriabit2021 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.totoria.tutoriabit2021, PID: 21586
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.totoria.tutoriabit2021/com.totoria.tutoriabit2021.Estudiantes}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3311)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3460)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2047)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
at com.totoria.tutoriabit2021.Estudiantes.onCreate(Estudiantes.java:36)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3286)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3460) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2047) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que declaraste "fabCamara" como `Button` cuando en realidad es un `FloatingActionButton`. Sucede que `FloatingActionButton` **no** es una subclase de `Button` sino que extiende a la clase `ImageButton`. Todo lo que tienes que hacer para solucionarlo es corregir el tipo de dato.

```
FloatingActionButton fabCamara;
```